# How to update drop down field based on another drop down field in Magento admin form?

Tags: magento

I have an admin form module. Where i need to populate list of states & cities , i have listed the states. Now, I need to populate the cities based on selected state.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: I have two dropdown fields in admin form. One drop down field has to be displayed based on another drop down field.

Scenario:-
1.Display countries in select drop down
2.Cities to be display based on country selected in Country field

Comment: can any one suggest me a solution for this?